# htaccess non-www. to www redirect AND request rewrite to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to combine two htaccess RewriteRules at the same time:

1) transform all non-www URLs to www
2) send all requests to index.php

Number 2 works with the following settings in production:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA]
```

but when combined with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

the URLs behave as supposed to when using a www url, but funnily when used with a non-www url.

E.g.
`http://mydomain.com/customername/admin/signin` becomes
`http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/admin/signin?/customername/admin/signin`

although the URL should just stay the same without a refresh and the parameters "/customername/admin/signin" should be passed to index.php...

Any tips on how I can achieve this? I want the URL after mydomain.com to stay the same (as my solution currently does) but add the www. infront of the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to add the HTTP_HOST checking *before* the catch-all rewrite to index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This redirects to www *before* any of the URI have been rewritten to the catch-all, then:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA]
```

Do the catch-all, which happens after the non-www gets 301 redirected to the www domain.

Comment: Thanks! Works as advertized! ;)