# htaccess www redirect for seo friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's what I want:

```
URL: http://www.domain.com/location/netherlands/amsterdam/amsterdam-airport
```

Now, what I want is if anyone open this url without www, he should get redirected to www.

Remember these are seo friendly url. I am already using MOD_REWRITE for the above url:

```
RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /location.php?country=$1&city=$2&location=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now if I do www redirect using any htaccess tricks. This is what I get:

```
http://www.domain.com/location.php?country=netherlands&city=amsterdam&location=amsterdam-airport
```

If you have any questions, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885947/htaccess-non-www-to-www-redirect-and-request-rewrite-to-index-php

Comment: that solution isnt working for me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have `www` rule before this existing rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^location/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /location.php?country=$1&city=$2&location=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also make sure to test in a different browser or clear your browser cache before testing.