# htaccess mod_rewrite combined with WWW. redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have seen many posts on here about both mod_rewrite and non-www. to www. sites. I have an issue with their combination. These rules work fine independently for me on different websites / servers

My standard force to WWW. rule is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I have this combined with a mod_rewrite to turn an address:

```
www.site.com/folder1/folder2
```

into:

```
www.site.com/category.php?catcode=folder1&pagetype=folder2
```

The code for this is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Both these code parts work on their own, but I have an issue when I try to reach this address:

http://example.com and it returns:

```
http://www.example.com/view_category.php?catcode=http:&page=www.example.com
```

Which is clearly not acceptable. What should be achieved is:

```
http://www.example.com [/index.php]
```

**Why is this not appearing to treat the Redirect 301 as a [L]ast request?**

## Things I have read/tried already:

[htaccess www redirect for seo friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734904/htaccess-www-redirect-for-seo-friendly-url)

[htaccess non-www. to www redirect AND request rewrite to index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885947/htaccess-non-www-to-www-redirect-and-request-rewrite-to-index-php)

Also I have tried to define that the mod_rewrite rule only applies to www. only, so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^www.%{HTTP_HOST}([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ www.%{HTTP_HOST}/view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

But this does not change the behaviour. the www. redirect *works* but it continues to try and load the mod_rewrite when there is no www. , the address **http://example.com/** does the same thing, but the addresses **http://www.example.com** and **http://www.example.com/** both behave correctly, which to me looks like the issue is not specifically the mod_rewrite.

I have also tried substituting **[L]** for **[END]** but with no difference in result.

( I have also tried removing the `options -indexes` just to see but this also changed nothing. )

The process works perfectly when used as intended, http://example.com/folder1/folder2 redirects correctly (to http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2).

## My .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 400     /error/400.php
ErrorDocument 401     /error/401.php
ErrorDocument 403     /error/403.php
ErrorDocument 404     /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500     /error/500.php
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

<Files php.ini>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

What have I missed?

Comment: any reason for the -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to change `([^/]*)` to `([^/]+)`.

The one you're using makes it match 0 or more characters, whereas the alternative makes it match 1 or more characters.

As you have made the trailing slash optional, a request to the root of the domain will match `([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$`.

So, your file should now look like this:

```bash
ErrorDocument 400     /error/400.php
ErrorDocument 401     /error/401.php
ErrorDocument 403     /error/403.php
ErrorDocument 404     /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500     /error/500.php

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /view_category.php?catcode=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

<Files php.ini>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>
```

Comment: I take that back, clearing my browser cache and reloading the site your solution seems to be working. Many thanks Mike!